# Error code is 0x80131500 when applying SP4 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, errors, service-pack

This is an open request for any thoughts, advice or guidance about an issue I have while attempting to apply SP4 to a SQL Server 2012 installation.

The server is currently the secondary node of a two-node AG and has been running well for several years. The SP file is on a local drive and I am running it from the RDP desktop. The error code is 0x80131500.

Though the things I have found so far about that error code all relate to Windows Store on Windows 10.

When I look in the setup logs for the SP I see a "Network Path Not found" error and it seems to be looking for the Primary node of this AG.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What SP is the primary node on?

Comment: can you post your setup bootstrap logs for this patch install (summary_xxx.txt and detail.txt) I would be able to analyse and provide much accurate advice/answer

Comment: I have preserved the two logs you're asking about. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to attach the logs here. What is the method for doing so?

Comment: scsimon, the nodes are all Sql Server 2012, SP3 w/ CU7 build 6579.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. I have found out that the network segment between the nodes of the AG had File and Printer Sharing disabled. Only Sql traffic was allowed.
Re-enabling that on both nodes of the AG for the time it takes to apply the patches on both nodes allowed the needed communication between them.

Just another reminder that you should always check the simple things first when you have a problem.

Have a great day
Richard